# How remove rows by id, got by group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I want to remove some rows from table.

First, i tried to use subquery, but I can't remove data from table, when use the same table in subquery.

I tried do that in another way.

```
set @list_id_remove = (select group_concat(mra.media_id) from movie AS m
right join media AS mra ON m.id = mra.media_id
where m.id is null);

delete from media
where media_id IN (@list_id_remove);
```

But in this case query remove only 1 row.
I think trouble - is that group_concat remove string and I need list of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to delete from `media` where the corresponding record doesn't exist in `movie`.  You can do this as a single query.

```
delete from media 
    where not exists (select 1 from movie m where m.id = media.media_id);
```

It does seem strange to me that the field `movie.id` would correspond to `media.media_id`, but that is how your original query is written.

EDIT:

As for your question, you can write the `delete` as:

```
delete from media
    where find_in_set(media_id, @list_id_remove) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, first query works, but add to query "where" before m.id = media.media_id

Comment: Servers in general will HEAR YOUR QUERIES BETTER IF YOU [CAPITALIZE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426138/why-are-the-queries-in-sql-mostly-written-in-capital-letters) YOUR CODE ;)

Comment: May be for the case asked in the question, this solution will work.
But for queries with 
delete from tableA where id in (select group_concat(id) from tableB where ....) does not work. It deletes only 1 record

Answer (score 0):

For the case posted in this post, there exists a solution without using group_concat. But there are scenarios where we use group_concat to collect deletable ids. `FIND_IN_SET` function will be handy for such situations.

```
delete 
from 
    media 
where 
    media_id FIND_IN_SET(media_id, (
        select
            group_concat(mra.media_id)
        from movie AS m
            right join media AS mra ON m.id = mra.media_id
        where 
            m.id is null
        ) d 
    );
```