# removing mysql group_concat selected rows

Tags: mysql

Although this question was asked two years ago the solutions did not use group_concat. so keeping it brief given a table

```
id    name
1     Tim
2     Sam
3     Bob
4     Joe
5     Ali
6     Kay
7     Bob
8     Joe
```

running the following

```
select name, count(*) c, group_concat(id) rows
  from table
 group by name
having c > 1;
```

gives

```
name   c   rows
Bob    2   3,7
Joe    2   4,8
```

is is possible to then remove rows 3,7,4 and 8 from my table without writing a script? I think I do need to use group_concat because in reality my "name" column is a concatenation of three columns in the table.

Comment: Why use `GROUP_CONCAT()` at all?  Just use a join: `DELETE t1 FROM table t1 NATURAL JOIN (SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2` ?

Comment: thanks this gave me some ideas, I eventually used short script with a similar looking query to select the id's I wanted to delete without group_concat and deleted each one.

Comment: Try this one when you really want to use group_concat to identify records to delete https://stackoverflow.com/a/75634133/2194375

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(`access`.id) as 
extra_access,`access`.perm_role_id,group_concat(temp.extra_id) as extra_ids
FROM `access`  
INNER JOIN(  
SELECT `access`.id,perm_role_id,perm_module_id,group_concat(id) as extra_id
FROM `access`
GROUP BY perm_role_id,perm_module_id     
HAVING COUNT(id) =1  
)temp ON access.id= temp.id GROUP BY perm_role_id
```

Use join again and concat again for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the duplicate row, try this

```
DELETE from table where id NOT IN (select id from table GROUP BY name having count(*) = 1)
```

delete all rows which are not unique